# setup installer vs 2010 64 bit changed platform

Tags: c#, 64-bit, setup-project

I created a setup installer in vs 2010 and it is in .net Platform 3.0. Because my app is 64 bit , I also made the setup installer x64 (solution explorer-> target platform). it compiled and build fine.
when I am ready to use it, I copied this installer file to another box and run it. It complains that I need .net platform 4.0. How is it possible? How to changed it back to 3.0? How to fix this?

Comment: Right-click your Setup project in the Solution Explorer window.  Properties, Prerequisites button.  Untick the .NET 4 Framework and pick the one you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes Visual Studio setup automatically adds a .NET Framework launch condition to the package. So you can try this:

- select your setup project in Solution Explorer
- click "Launch Conditions Editor" button in Solution Explorer top pane
- modify or remove the .NET Framework launch condition